# Are determiners mandatory in Chinese?

Tags: grammar

This question might sound weird.

Are determiners mandatory in Chinese?

I have in mind words such as demonstratives 这, quantifying words 一些, 许多, etc.

This paper (Chen 2004) states:

> Finally, we turn to the last question: is it justified to assert that
> definiteness as a grammatical category, in the narrow sense of the
> term, exists in Chinese? English presents an exemplary case for the
> existence of definiteness as a grammatical category, as the language
> displays a paradigmatic contrast between two simple, fully
> grammaticalized articles, one definite and the other indefinite. (...)
> Chinese, however, represents a case that does not accord very well
> with what has been established for these languages in the current
> literature. To begin with, there is no simple, fully grammaticalized
> marker of definiteness in Chinese, like the definite article in
> English. (...) Furthermore, it is not obligatory to mark a nominal
> expression as either definite or indefinite in Chinese, as is the case
> in English.

In contrast, this paper (Orvig et al. 2013) concerning French determiners states:

> In French – except for certain non-referential uses (see Table 2
> below) – determiners (Leeman, 2004) are mandatory to actualize a noun
> and convey the marks of gender and number.

So I am looking for a scientific reference which states something echoing the statement in the paper on French, something like "Determiners are not mandatory to actualize a noun and convery the marks of gender and number."

**References:**

Chen, P. (2004). Identifiability and definiteness in Chinese. *Linguistics*, 42, 1129-1184.

Orvig, A. S., Marcos, H., Caët, S., Corlateanu, C., Da Silva, C., Hassan, R., ... & Morgenstern, A. (2013). Definite and indefinite determiners in French-speaking toddlers: Distributional features and pragmatic-discursive factors. *Journal of pragmatics*, 56, 88-112.

Comment: Please provide some example sentences/phrases that you have questions with. Also, I don't think this is a place to ask for "reference" but "answers".

Comment: For starters, there are no gender and number in Chinese. So it appears that "determiners" are not necessary. However, as r13 said, some examples would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

The way that Chinese expresses "definite or indefinite" is called "特指" and "泛指". There are a couple of ways to indicate your "所指" （the signified object）。For example,

这屋里有一个坏人。There is a bad guy in the room.

这个人是坏人。This person is a bad guy.

这屋里谁是坏人？Who is the bad guy in the room?

这个人是坏人吗？Is the person a bad guy?

"特指" and "泛指" can use "这个" or "一个" to determine the meaning of "definite" (the) or "indefinite" (a), but it is not a strict grammar rule. Generally, Chinese grammar rules are very loose, flexible, or "inaccurate". It also heavily relies on the "context" of the dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

without a determiner, it sounds you're making statement about some general class/set of things/men or concept, without conditions.

“famous sayings” are often like this. for example:

人类总是犯同样的错误。